# use PHP to insert the info into the div

Tags: php

I need help. I have a task and I don't understand this question well on what I am doing.I just started learning PHP, so I only know some basics
In PHP only do the following: make a variable hold a string value of the weather. Write a div with an id of weather in HTML and use PHP to insert the weather into the div.
I have a div:

```
<div id="wether">

</div>
```

thanks !

Comment: How does this have anything to do with Java?

Comment: You haven't even shown what you have tried doing. Also Java is definitely not PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a php file with following content

```
<?php $weatherValue = "Your value here"; ?>
<div id="weather">
  <?php echo $weatherValue; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: If i did that , how to exit PHP and make a div in HTML and then use PHP to put the weather value into a div.And do the same without exiting PHP. What does the exit PHP means in general?